# Python 2.x and using formatters like %s, %d etc

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am learning how to code with python using "Learn Python the HARD WAY" 3rd edition.
I am on Exercise 6. Im not having to much trouble although the formatters still have me a tad confused.
I know the formatter %s is used for strings.
But I am confused about when to use others and why to use others
like:%r, %d, %x, etc.....
Any direction would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You probably don't need to stress. They are old-style formatters. Just use `"Hello {}".format(your_name)` and don't worry about the data type. LPTHW has a lot of issues, not least because it seems to have convinced you to start with Python 2 which will be unmaintained after 2020 (note, I followed the course myself)

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python format tutorial", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: FYI: https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints

Comment: also: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: I wonder why so many people want to learn python the hard way, when there are a lot of easy ways to do so. This book has many flaws. Forget about it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre as someone who had never programmed and I was looking for a way to learn, the format was far more appealing and appeared more structured than any other tutorial I found. Without prior knowledge, you can't make _any_ serious judgement on the quality of the content

Comment: the title of the book is ill-chosen if you ask me. Do you want to suffer? YES!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre or, it expresses that it intends not to hand-hold and actually accelerate your understanding. The best way to learn a spoken language is to be immersed in it even when you don't know what people are saying

Comment: okay, then it's a bit like "only medecine that tastes bad is good for your health" :) or any army movie.

Comment: Thanks for all the input thus far! I will definitely check out those 2 websites.

Comment: As for learning using this book...Im pretty sure the title is just a play on words because its been extremely easy to learn what I have learned this far. Ive tried taking an online Python course from EDx but it was a little beyond me.

Comment: I am open to any sources you have for learning python. And when I started I wasn't sure if I should start with Python 2.x or 3.x I was just really eager to get the ball rolling.

Comment: @B.S. If you learn Python 2 for now, it's not the end of the world, you can change easily enough later. Keep the criticism here in mind but don't be put off; it won't teach you anything that can't be fixed so if you really want to keep going with the course, the main thing is indulging your curiosity more than having everything exactly right at the start. You will find it useful to google around each of the topics though, or just google random questions on a topic and see what others are doing

Answer (score 0):

`%r`, `%d`, `%x`, `%s` are [String formatters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting).

- `%d` formatter is used for numbers
- `%s` formatter will the string representation of the object (makes use of `str()`)
- `%r` formatter will return the canonical string representation of the object (makes use of `repr()`)
- `%x` is used for signed hexadecimal. The alternate form causes a leading ‘0x’ to be inserted between left-hand padding and the formatting of the number if the leading character of the result is not already a zero.

You might also find [this article](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/formatting.html) useful that contains most -if not all- formatters.